# Discover the six-character password!

Tags: mathematics, number-theory, password, number-property

You are given several pieces of paper which are as follows:

[image: puzzle picture]

<sup><sub>(Unfortunately, a textual rendering is very difficult with this puzzle, so if someone can offer a suggestion on how to do it, that would be wonderful.)</sub></sup>

You need to figure out what the six-character password is... Ready, set, go!

#### Hint 1:

> Use the two outer numbers to get the middle numbers for each group of three.

#### Hint 2:

> Read deeper into the question. Be a detective!

#### Hint 3:

> Check the re______ h_s__r_! That's how true detectives are made!

#### Hint 4:

> Follow this set of operations on some of the numbers you get from  the triplets: ad, su, mo

#### Hint 5:

> First step is to add the two numbers... Then, subtract some numbers that you can get after adding the two numbers...

---

***AFTER THIS BOUNTY ENDS, I WILL POST THE ANSWER***

Comment: If we are to interpret that the central number of each triplet is derived from the two either side, then rot13(gur rknzcyrf tvira fhttrfg gung vs lbh fhogenpg gur yrsg-unaq ahzore sebz gur evtug-unaq ahzore, n artngvir erfhyg tvirf 0 naq na rira aba-artngvir erfhyg tvirf K, jvgu bgure ahzoref cebqhprq va fbzr jnl ol bqq aba-artngvir erfhygf. Fvapr gur cnffpbqr qvssreraprf ner *nyy* artngvir be rira aba-artngvir [0,16,-91,6,-2,12] guvf jbhyq ranoyr hf gb vtaber gur aba-0-be-K rknzcyrf naq tnva na nafjre bs **KK0K0K**) - I'm guessing this isn't the answer you intended...??

Comment: @Stiv - No, because your rule does not match what is given in the puzzle.

Comment: There are rot13(n ahzore bs cevzrf naq frzv-cevzrf) in the question... Is that relevant or am I grasping at straws?

Comment: @Johnson - Yes, you are grasping at straws. :) Focus on doing something to the two outside numbers to get the inside number.

Comment: Hint 2 suggests the solution isn't just pure mathematics, but I've spent an hour staring at the question and nothing comes to mind.

Comment: @someone - Unfortunately, no...

Comment: @NibblyPig - If you don't understand what Hint 2 is saying, don't spend too much time focusing on that. Just try to get the mathematics of it.

Comment: Is the answer rot13(eryngrq gb nfpvv punenpgref)?

Comment: @simonalexander2005 - I won't say if it is or isn't!

Comment: That answer seems more enigmatic than your others, perhaps that's a clue? rot13(Gur fhz bs gur bhgre ahzoref tvirf gur nfpvv pbqr sbe gur zvqqyr bar sbe gur gjb va gur gbc-evtug, ng yrnfg)

Comment: All this rot13 stuff makes me think I'm way out of my depth by just trying to multiply the numbers together and stuff. I think I'm in the wrong place.

Comment: @NibblyPig https://cryptii.com/pipes/rot13-decoder - it's just a way of preventing spoilers

Comment: Oh I see, whoops!

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath Hint 3 - I already found that extra clue but it didn't help

Comment: @simonalexander2005 - Is hint 4 maybe more helpful?

Comment: It's a tough one! I'm one the same track as @simonalexander2005, and hint 4 only confirmed that it may be the right track, but I hardly made any progress.

Comment: At first I spotted an intriguing pattern, suggesting rot18(K rdhnyf 9) and involving rot18(ybt onfr 7), but the observation that rot18(K naq bar bs gur 8'f ner whfg nfpvv punef) made me drop that idea.

Comment: Now I just tried to guess the password, see my answer below,
based on rot18(03k19=677=nfpvv m)

Comment: Oops, rot18(V zrnag cyhf)

Comment: @simonalexander2005 - Added hint 5. Wanna try again?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the password is

> 2X3201

The method is the following

> 1. Add the two outer numbers to get a sum (S)
>  2. Seperate the sum into its last digit and the digit(s) in front of it. Get the absolute difference between these two (D).
>  3. Find S MOD D
>
>  As an example take $73, 5, 84$. The sum of the outer numbers is $73+84=157$. This is seperated into $15$ and $7$. Their absolute difference is $15 - 7 =8$. Now, $157$ MOD $8 = 5$, which is the middle number.

Comment: I like this very much

Comment: I agree with balazs. I like this very much. So much so, in fact, that I will give this a shiny green check and a blasting blue upvote as well as a royal bounty! :D Congrats on the great answer!

Answer (score 0):

Ooohh, wait! Aha! I'm going to take a shortcut,

> based on just one character

and guess the password is

> puzzle

Don't ask me the complete recipe, I still don't know yet!

Explanation:

> The most obvious way to combine any two numbers is to try and add them. This doesn't directly render the middle number in any of the triplets. But: The fourth piece of paper, the one with the X, suggests that the middle numbers are not really numbers but characters. Indeed, 31+57=88=ascii'X'. The same holds for the third piece of paper, 9+42=51=ascii'3'. For the other papers this doesn't work. The second one yields 3+16=19, the ascii value of a non printing character, not of '3', which is 51. But the difference is 32, meaning it is shifted to the next column of the ascii table. So there seems to be some recipe. For the remaining papers the recipe appears to be more complicated, and I give up for now. Trying the simple adding recipe on the paper with the six triplets yields only one letter: 'z' on the fourth position. So we have '---z--'. The rest is just a bold guess!

Now I can't wait to press these buttons and see if the door swings open!

Comment: Without any explanation this doesn't answer the puzzle at all - it should probably be left as a comment instead... Also you don't need to use rot in a spoiler block - that's what the spoiler block is for :)

Comment: How is the password a word when you are supposed to get a number from the two outside ones?

Comment: @Stiv, got rid of the rot now, I was just being overly cautious.

Comment: @Stiv, explanation added to my answer.

Comment: The answer deserves an upvote. However, I think Hint 2 and Hint 3 render the first argument of your reasoning incorrect.

Comment: Added hint 5. Wanna try again?

Comment: Is the password rot18(708569)? Probably not, because that would imply an error on the second piece of paper, or I still haven't figured out the correct recipe. Hmmmpf! Better have another cup of coffee...

Answer (score -1):

Answer:

> 21 19 51 88 157 17 49 78

Reason:

> The puzzle is 6 digits long. If we add up the numbers on either side we get the following numbers. So that means that the answer must be the numbers above.

Comment: How is this possible? Your answer is nowhere near 6 characters long.

Comment: Added hint 5. Wanna try again?